# Apache Fuseki: Exposing only SPARQL endpoint interface

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I successfully installed Apache Fuseki 2.4.0 and uploaded some triples in it. In the configurations, I disabled fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore, fuseki:serviceUpdate and fuseki:serviceUpload, which makes it impossible for someone to modify my dataset.

However, the fuseki server page still shows all option, including "upload file", "edit" and other.

Fuseki's sparql endpoint graphical interface is very nice, but I wanted to expose only this interface to let user type in their queries.

Is this possible?

Comment: The UI does not adapt to the functionality available.  The operations will not work though.

Comment: You can also restrict the Fuseki's UI to localhost and expose publicly a only basic SPARQL front-end, such as [Pubby](http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pubby/), that would proxy Fuseki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndyS posted this as a comment, but I think it answers the question, so I'm adding it as a community wiki answer.  (If AndyS posts it as an answer, I'll remove this one.)

> The UI does not adapt to the functionality available. The operations will not work though.  – AndyS [20 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297764/apache-fuseki-exposing-only-sparql-endpoint-interface#comment64033565_38297764)